# Mysql how to improve Update query to perform faster

Tags: mysql, set, sql-update

I am trying to update about 30k records using inner join update query.. but it is taking too long.. I am using mysql version 5.0.5 any other way to perform this task.. it is taking about half an hour for each query.. how to improve this query to perform faster.. any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE a_station t1
INNER JOIN a_trains t2 ON 
t1.Station_Code =t2.Station_Code AND t1.Train_No =t2.Train_No
SET t1.Isl_No = t2.Isl_No,
   t1.Distance = t2.Distance,
   t1.Train_Type = t2.Train_Type;
```

Comment: Have you performed proper indexing?

Comment: By indexing you mean a primary key..? But primary key would be different of both the table....

Comment: Provide table schema